# Simple graph layout in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to draw a simple graph with **d3.js** like this one

[image]

I failed to find out the graph layout in both in v5 API documentation and on the Internet.

All examples use `d3.force` layout  from [d3-force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force). Although it looks impressive, I am not looking for a graph layout with physicall simulation.

Is there a simpler layout or is the best way to use `d3.force` layout with switched off physics ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need to use the `d3.forceSimulation`, that ultimately is just one of the many D3 layouts that are on offer. If you look at Mike Bostocks example [Force Directed Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) then the modifications you need are as follows:

1. Define a set of `nodes` - basically an array of things to represent the circles
2. Append the `svg:circle` elements to the DOM using `.data(nodes)`
3. Defined a set of `links`
4. Append the `svg:line` elements to the DOM using `.data(links)`

This is essentially using `D3` for it's pure DOM data binding, and not using a pre-built layout.

You can copy any of the force example really - all it's doing underneath is setting an `x` and a `y` position underneath. If you've already got those, just position your circles at those points.

All the parts to do with `simulation` and the `ticked` event you can remove from the example.

Here is an example providing a static layout:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

const layout = (graph) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .alphaMin(0.3)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on("end", resolve(graph));

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
  });
};

const render = (graph) => {

  var link = d3.select("#target").append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  var node = d3.select("#target").append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });
}


d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
 
  layout(graph)
     .then((graph) => render(graph));
});
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600">
   <g id="target" transform="translate(480, 300)">
   </g>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**

To change the distance between the nodes you need to change some of the forces in play. The docs are really good - specifically what you want to change is https://github.com/d3/d3-force#many-body

So modify the `charge` force to read:

```
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-charge))
```

You'll need to define the charge, and tweak it a little until the force gives you a good layout.

Comment: NOTE: When I visit the link you provided I get **Application error**

Comment: The reason why I need layout is that I want x and y calculated for me for nodes and links like in tree layout for example.

Comment: @Zak looks like bl.ocks.org is down at the moment. It'll be only temporary so I'll leave the link in for now. The source can be seen at https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4062045

Comment: @dev-null you can use any layout you wish to calculate the positions. You could even use the force - allow it to run for a few hundred miliseconds, stop it, and take the positions that it produced. There's no need to keep it running/restarting it giving the motion effects.

Comment: @dev-null I've added an example of using the force just to calculate the layout - and then split off the rendering. If you wanted you could change that `layout` function to run a `tree` layout, a `circle pack` layout - or any other custom layout you want.

Comment: Ok. I see the results. But they are quite tightly packed. How do I regulate how far away should they be ? Also, do I understand it correctly that if I want a graph a layout this is my best bet ? I don't want `tree` layout (and besides doesn't it require rooted tree-like hierarchy?) and thought `circle pack` is for grouping which wouldn't fit my case.

Comment: @dev-null yeah it does feel like the `forceSimulation` is the best layout for you. Highly recommend you look at the API docs (they're not that long) https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceSimulation . But I'll update my answer